# escaping a JS reserved word (already double encapsulated)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS function which is generated by some PHP, the function call is below:

```
onClick=openPopup('".$row['imgname']."','".$row['adtitle']."','".$row['adviews']."')
```

Now this works unless the value of $row['adtitle'] contains a JS keyword. The one that brought the bug in my code to my attention was the word 'THIS'. Would there be a way to escape these values, I can't figure it out as I have already used a lot of encapsulation in this call.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
 `openPopup('efc86f7223790e91f423ef1b73278435.jpg','THIS IS A TEST ADVERT 12345678','2')`
This call does not work.

`openPopup('eada91a6c1197d2f2320e59f45d8ca6b.jpg','is a test','2')` 
however this one does work..

only thing I could figure was the `THIS` as when looking at the source, the text following `THIS` is highlighed differently.

Edit 2 : Here is my function:

```
function openPopup(imgname,adtitle,adviews) {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('delimg').src = 'imgstore/' + imgname;
    document.getElementById('delAdTitle').innerHTML = adtitle;
    document.getElementById('delAdViews').innerHTML = adviews;
    document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = function() {
        location.href = '?delete=1&id=' + imgname;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Gah. Escapement hell.

Comment: You can have as many reserved keywords as you'd like in a string, and with the way the arguments are quoted it sure looks like those are strings ?

Comment: This is how the js looks after php has done its stuff... `openPopup('efc86f7223790e91f423ef1b73278435.jpg','THIS IS A TEST ADVERT 12345678','2')`   This call does not work.

Comment: `openPopup('eada91a6c1197d2f2320e59f45d8ca6b.jpg','is a test','2')`  however this one does work.. only thing I could figure was the `THIS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it’s just a question of proper formatting:

```
$onclick = 'openPopup('.json_encode($row['imgname']).','.json_encode($row['adtitle']).','.json_encode($row['adviews']).')';
echo 'onClick="'.htmlspecialchars($onclick).'"';
```

Note that we’re abusing `json_encode` here to quote the JavaScript string literals. Although we shouldn’t as strictly speaking [JSON strings are not a subset of JavaScript strings](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset).

Comment: Using this                                                                  `$onclick = "openPopup(".json_encode($row['imgname']).",".json_encode($row['adtitle'].",".json_encode($row['adviews']).")";`                            gives me an error `unexpected ;`

Comment: Never mind ... you missed out a ) on 2nd string, this works great now thanks!

Comment: With [unquoted attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-\(unquoted\)-state) the first space actually delimits the attribute value.